Can I alter the URL of xmlsitemap?
Is it possible to add a separate xmlsitemap for different content types using xmlsitemap module?
Eg: I already have https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml for all content types, need a separate https://www.example.com/sitemap-article.xml in the same website for article CT.
Or is it possible for me to alter the URL of sitemaps/sitemap-article/sitemap.xml to just /sitemap-article.xml? I'm using Simple sitemap module.
I installed Simple sitemap module because I wanted different sitemap for different CT, let me know if I can use the first module and get the result. I am using d10 website.

As far as I know, yes.
Use URL aliases in Configuration > Search and Metadata > URL Aliases. Now
create a URL alias that points /sitemap/sitemap-article.xml to /sitemap-article.xml.
Note that don't forget to update Robots.txt file.

Nope, it is still redirecting me to /sitemaps/sitemap-article/sitemap.xml.
Also getting an error if I add /sitemap-article.xml "Either the path '/sitemap-news.xml' is invalid or you do not have access to it."

@ShashankS maybe you dont have permission in your .htaccess file...
